# How to get number of month after the month change using datatimepicker in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker, desktop-application, monthcalendar

I have two datetimepicker lets take name **datetimepicker1** and **datetimepicker2** now **datetimepicker1** is for the **registration** date while **datetimepicker2** is for the **money interest paid** date.

Now I want to count **month** after the **month change** using **datetimepicker**

For understanding clearing lets take one example 
**datetimepicker1** registration date is **27/31/2019** and user has come to paid her money interest at 10/01/2020 i.e. **datetimepicker2** store value is **10/01/2020**

Now I want take interest money of two month **27/31/2019** is for **december** month and **10/01/2020** for the **january** month.

So how can I show the value **2** in textbox?

Here is my try code

```
textbox.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32((datetimepicker2.Value - datetimepicker1.Value).TotalDays) / 31);
```

Now according by this code, I am getting 1 month after datetimepicker2 select the **27/01/2020** or greater than, which I dont want.

[image]

Image shows the debug code and format of the date.

Comment: Your subtraction is backwards.  Should be : datetimepicker2.Value - datetimepicker1.Value

Comment: @jdweng oops sorry, I edited the question please review it.

Comment: In what calendar is this **27/31/2019** ?

Comment: @JQSOFT this is datetimepicker of windows application with dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: 27/31/2019 is not a valid date on any calendar.

Comment: @JQSOFT I have add the image in question please review it.

Comment: How is interest computed?  Interest is computed different depending on country.  There are only 360 banking days a year (12 months evenly divided) in most countries.  To get end of month usually you would use AddMonth and then subtract one day so you don't have to calculate the number of days in a month.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do enum structure for names of months and its order numbers and in switch case i.e if the datetimepicker for registration in January will give in returns 1, same with may will give in returns 5 then you can do the subtraction here... Hopefully you get what i meant...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Timespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) to the calculations.

Also, when you calculate month difference, instead of adding 31 days randomly in your calculation. You can check modulus value and if its  greater than zero you can add +1 to month.

```
 int month = TimeSpan.Days/31;
 if(TimeSpan.Days%31 >0 ) month +=1;
```